# start docker file under the directory

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have application like this, this is made by another person.

I am not familliar with docker so much though, I need to start the application.

The directory structure is like this,

```
/docker/amazon.Dockerfile
/firstapp/
/secondapp/
.gitignore
manage.py
```

So, I try this command `docker build docker/amazon.Dockerfile`

error comes.

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: error from sender: walk docker/aws.Dockerfile: not a directory
```

then, `docker build docker`

This error comes,

```
failed to solve with frontend dockerfile.v0: failed to read dockerfile: open /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount426516845/Dockerfile: no such file or directory
```

Where should I start with this project??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use something like this:

```
docker image build -f docker/amazon.Dockerfile .
```

with -f you specify a custom path for your Dockerfile and a trailing . is needed to specify the docker context for your new docker image.